# How to run it on another Qt thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5, qthread

With [Qthread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) in mind I tried the following but it seems everything is still running in the same thread.

main.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"

#include <QApplication>

#include "core.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << QThread::currentThreadId();

    Core core;

    Widget w(core);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

func.h

```
#ifndef FUNC_H
#define FUNC_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

class Func : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Func()
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << QThread::currentThreadId();
    }

    void compute()
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << QThread::currentThreadId();
    }
};

#endif // FUNC_H
```

core.h

```
#ifndef CORE_H
#define CORE_H

#include <QObject>

#include "func.h"

class Core : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QThread thread;
    Func* func = nullptr;

public:
    explicit Core(QObject *parent = nullptr)
    {
        func = new Func();
        func->moveToThread(&thread);
        connect(&thread, &QThread::finished, func, &QObject::deleteLater);
        thread.start();
    }

    ~Core() {
        thread.quit();
        thread.wait();
    }

public slots:
    void compute(){func->compute();}

signals:

};

#endif // CORE_H
```

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

#include "core.h"

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget(Core& core)
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << QThread::currentThreadId();

        core.compute(); // This should run on a different thread ?
    }

};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

Running I get the output:

```
int main(int, char **) 0x107567e00
Func::Func() 0x107567e00
Widget::Widget(Core &) 0x107567e00
void Func::compute() 0x107567e00
```

Above output was from macOS but in Windows I got similar result.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call the slot `compute()` directly, it will call it in the same thread as runs the code which called it (as you can see in the output).

You need to run the slot via signals/slots mechanism (or with `invokeMethod()`, but let's ignore this one).

Typically this is done by connecting thread's `started()` signal to the slot and then calling `QThread::start()` from the main thread. It will result in slot being called in the secondary thread just after the thread gets started.

Comment: Got it! And it would be interesting to have a warning when calls to methods on that object are not made indirectly. Any suggestion on this aspect? Ideally I would like to guarantee calls to methods on that object run on another thread (only).